# Chart.js: Legends for two datasets in Doughnut Chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js, donut-chart

I have a Chart.js Doughnut Chart with two datasets. The chart itself works great, but the legend doesn't display as I would expect.

[image]

The three colours of the first dataset get displayed correctly in the legend. But the second dataset is not referenced to the Doughnut at all. It just shows all the labels, but gets its colour from the first colour of the first dataset.

How can I have a proper legend for both datasets?

This is my code:

```
data = {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Orange', 'Dings', 'Bums', 'Yada'],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [300, 50, 100],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: ['#CB4335', '#1F618D', '#F1C40F']
      },
      {
        data: [345.56, 56.47, 987.12, 78.01],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: ['#ff5604', '#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff']
      }
    ]
  };

  chartConfig = {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: this.data,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          onClick: this.handleClick,
          onHover: this.handleHover,
          onLeave: this.handleLeave
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: I think it's similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73526598/chartjs-labels-dont-match-with-chart/73527971#73527971

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you use Chart.js version 3.x or higher.

Fill the legend background color in the first dataset.

You set null or ' ' for 'data', 'backgroundColor' fields respectively like below example.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var data = {
  labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Pink', 'Lightgreen', 'Tomato', 'Orange'],
  datasets: [
    {
      data: [300, 50, 100, null, null, null, null, null],
      backgroundColor: ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'pink', 'lightgreen', 'tomato', 'orange'],
    },
    {
      data: [null, null, null, 345.56, 56.47, 987.12, 78.01],
      backgroundColor: [null, null, null, 'pink', 'lightgreen', 'tomato', 'orange'],
    },
  ],
};

var options = {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      onClick: this.handleClick,
      onHover: this.handleHover,
      onLeave: this.handleLeave,
    },
  },
};

var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data,
  options,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.0-beta.6/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

**[Example: Legends for Multiple Chart Different Colors](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-znuks1?file=index.js)**

[image]

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var data = {
  labels: ['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Tomato', 'Pink', 'Gray'],
  datasets: [
    {
      data: [20, 40, 50, null, null, null, null, null],
      backgroundColor: ['#ff6384', '#ff9f40', '#ffcd56', '#4bc0c0', '#36a2eb', 'tomato', 'pink', 'gray'],
    },
    {
      data: [null, null, null, 60, 10, 20],
      backgroundColor: [null, null, null, '#4bc0c0', '#36a2eb', 'tomato'],
    },
    {
      data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, 20, 40],
      backgroundColor: [null, null, null, null, null, null, 'pink', 'gray'],
    },
  ],
};

var options = {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      onClick: this.handleClick,
      onHover: this.handleHover,
      onLeave: this.handleLeave,
    },
  },
};

var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data,
  options,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.0-beta.6/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```